# routing with redirect and automatic child route transition with unexpected behavior

Tags: redirect, ember.js, routes

I have a routing related question.

```
App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('whiteBoards',function(){
        this.resource('whiteBoard',{path:'/:whiteBoard_id'},function(){
            this.resource('image');
            this.resource('video');
          });
    });
    this.resource('dummy');
});

App.WhiteBoardsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return this.store.find('whiteBoard');
    }
});
App.ImageRoute =  Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return this.store.find('image');
    }
});
```

If I click all navigational links manually all things works as expected.

my templates:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">

            <!-- Be sure to leave the brand out there if you want it shown -->
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/index.html">Routing Test</a>
        </div>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>{{#link-to 'whiteBoards'}}WhiteBoard{{/link-to}}</li>
            <li>{{#link-to 'dummy'}}Dummy{{/link-to}}</li>

        </ul>

        </div>

       </nav>

    {{outlet}}

</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="whiteBoards">

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs whiteBoards">

        {{#each whiteBoard in controller.content}}

        <li>
            {{#link-to 'whiteBoard' whiteBoard}}{{whiteBoard.title}} {{/link-to}}
        </li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>

    {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="whiteBoard">
    <div class="whiteBoard">
        <H3>WhiteBoard   {{controller.content.name}}</H3>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li>
            {{#link-to 'image'}}Images{{/link-to}}
        </li>
        <li>
            {{#link-to 'video'}}Videos{{/link-to}}
        </li>
    </ul>
 {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="image">
    <div class="imagelist">
        <H3>Images</H3>
        <ul>
            {{#each img in controller.content}}
            <li>{{img.name}}</li>
            {{/each}}

        </ul>
    </div>
</script>
```

The problem occurs if I try to activate the image route (as default child route) in combination with a whiteBoard navigation click.
This mean If I select a whiteBoard a list of images should also be shown (here only a simplified image list).

To achieve this I insert:

```
App.WhiteBoardIndexRoute =  Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect: function(){
        this.transitionTo('image');
    }
});
```

The first time it works as expected (the selected whiteBoard is shown and the image list).
If I try to navigate to another whiteBoard the problems begins.
After inserting WhiteBoardIndexRoute I can't navigate to another whiteBoard.
What is the problem ?

I'm working with ember.js verion 1.0

I known that I can implement the display of the image list using the renderTemplate method in the WhiteBoardRoute but I think that it should be possible to use the "default child route concept".